# how to tell mobileinit to pause executing until json is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I told jquerymobile to postpone executing mobileinit until DOM is loaded?

I'm trying to create pages on the fly using templates & JSON.  My problem is that JSON takes too long to load and jquerymobile has finished mobileinit event!

Example code:

```
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        console.log("mobileinit");

        // get JSON & set template... should wait until this is done!
        getData();

        //SWIPE SWIPE
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swipeleft", function(){
            var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, 'slide');
            }
        });
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swiperight", function(){
            var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, 'slide', true);
            }
        });
        console.log("mobileinit done");
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `getData()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to accomplish this.

```
// Let's assume that getData returns a deferred.
function getData() {
    return $.get('your/request/url');
});

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    // Now you can use the deferred returned from the getData function.
    getData().done(function() {
        //SWIPE SWIPE
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swipeleft", function() {
            var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, 'slide');
            }
        });
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swiperight", function() {
            var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, 'slide', true);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `getData()` function contains an `$.ajax` call, you'll need to put the reset of the init code within the `success` function of the `getData()`'s `$.ajax` call